# Upload document and set signatures with Docusign API

Tags: c#, docusignapi, electronic-signature, signaturepad

I am assuming with the Docusign developer API I will be able to list documents, their statuses, even have people sign documents within my app. However, I am wondering if the API covers uploading and setting the signature areas of the document.

It would be ideal if I can do everything through my Application.

Upload
List (w/ statuses)
Signatures

I am going to assume the upload and setting signature locations portion will all need to be done through the docusign site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the DocuSign API enables you to do all of the workflows in your question.

- Upload documents and sign them -- See the [C# example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core) and file [Eg001EmbeddedSigningController.cs](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg001EmbeddedSigningController.cs)
- List envelopes (transactions) and their status. See file [Eg003ListEnvelopesController.cs](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg003ListEnvelopesController.cs)

As an alternative to polling DocuSign for status, you can also add a webhook so DocuSign will make an HTTP POST to your server when an envelope's status changes.

Comment: The example shows how to create an evelope and add documents all in one go.is there a way to add a document to an existing envelope using the SDK?

Comment: @DeniroSA -- yes. Please ask as a new question